# Can’t insert NULL when variable could be either date time or NULL using labview

Tags: sql, datetime, null, labview

I am using labview to query an SQL table, I am manipulating the data and inserting it into a new table. Two of the columns are datetime and can either be a date or a NULL but the format into string needs quotes ‘%s’ to insert the datetime or I get an error whereas the NULL will only insert when I have no quotes %s.
Is there an easy way to solve this for both? As I am sending in rows of about 30 columns and it is only when I come across a NUll in the datetime column that it errors?

Comment: As the *sql tag* description suggests, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS

Comment: Looks like labview can be used as a front-end to a relational database.  Where is the data actually being stored?  E.g., Access, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.  The solution to your problem might be dependent on the storage platform.

Comment: There are several LabVIEW libraries for accessing databases. Which toolkit are you using? The "LabVIEW Database Connectivity Toolkit" from NI or one of the others from various third parties?

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL query for the select to use an ifnull and return a date you know would be null. I would suggest the LabVIEW epoch of 1st January 1904 formatted to match whatever is normally in your database

Comment: Can you supply an example?

Comment: SELECT ifnull(timestamp,"1904-01-01 00:00:00") FROM mytable;
Here you go this replaces time stamp the time stamp value if it is a null.